# Javascript map sorted by update/insertion order

Tags: javascript, object, maps

In javascript, is there a data structure that tracks insertion/update order?
for instance, if you have:

```
map[a]=1
map[b]=2
map[c]=3
```

I would want to get the keys in order a,b,c
but if I had

```
map[a]=1
map[b]=2
map[c]=3
map[b]=4
```

I would want the keys in order a,c,b since b was last updated.

I'm currently doing this with a js object and a sorted list to track update order. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is something out of the box, so the best way is probably either asking to Google or doing it yourself as you're doing currently!

Comment: Do you have an actual problem? If so add a [mcve], otherwise asking for an opinion ("is there a better way") is off-topic.

Comment: So, b comes before c but not a because it was last updated. But initial insertion of a,b,c doesn't put c before b because it was last inserted. Your description is unclear. I'm voting to close because of this. Please try to give a real world use cases of a problem to solve. Contrived examples rarely help. The closest implementation of what you've described is a linked-list.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object with a trap for [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set). Use a `set` to keep track of all the keys in the object. Every time you set a property, you can delete the key from the set before adding it. This ensures that the key just updated is always enumerated at the end.

A [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is used because, integer-like keys are [enumerated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219) before the string keys, irrespective of the order they are inserted. A set will keep the order of insertion. As suggested by @Kaiido, you can add an [`ownKeys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/ownKeys) trap. When the keys of the object are requested, then will be returned from the Set and the keys will be returned in the order of the Set.

```js
const createHandler = (keys = new Set) => ({
  set(obj, prop, value) {
    keys.delete(prop);
    keys.add(prop);
    return Reflect.set(...arguments)
  },
  ownKeys(obj) {
    return Array.from(keys)
  }
})

const map = new Proxy({}, createHandler())

map.a = 1,
map.b = 2;
map[1] = "integer-like key"

console.log(Object.keys(map))

map.c = 3;
map.b = 5

console.log(Object.keys(map))
```

Comment: I think that using `ownKeys` you could also handle numeric keys: https://jsfiddle.net/0u9qzLaw/

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, I have updated the answer. I added a factory function for creating the handler to avoid polluting the scope and make it easy for multiple objects of this type to be created.